# How to use nested Python dictionaries and D3.js?

Tags: python, json, d3.js, flask

I have a Python/Flask app that gathers data from third-party APIs and stores them in a JSON-like structure (nested Python dictionaries called 'results').

I'm sending this to my template using:

```
def format_results():
   item_data = {'name':name, 'age':age, 'address':address}
   results = {'title':item_title, 'item_data':item_data}    
   return jsonify(results)

@app.route('/')
def display_results():
    data = format_results()
    return render_template('index.html', data = data)
```

I would like to use d3.js in my template to plot the results on a graph.
What's the recommended way for doing so? (disclaimer: this is my first time using D3.js)

Comment: @Amber -- I've tried assigning it to a js variable: var da = {{ data }} but I don't think this is right. Also, I could have tried writing the python dictionaries to a valid .json file and then reading the file from the template but I would rather not go this route.

Comment: I recently needed to do this for work the var da = {{ data }} approach is bad unless you're ok with your js being confined to a django template. I just used json and have no problems with the result, why are are you opposed to going that route?

Comment: @blackfedora -- I'm not really opposed to using a json file instead. It just feels like there could be other options. If there aren't any, then that will be the way to go.

Comment: why use a json file when you can just pass a json'd string?

Comment: I just used a hidden input field with the json string like so. <input id="D3Data" type="hidden" value="{{ data }}">

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a way to make this work!

```
def format_results():
   item_data = {'name':name, 'age':age, 'address':address}
   results = {'title':item_title, 'item_data':item_data}    
   return results

@app.route('/')
def display_results():
    data = format_results()
    return render_template('index.html', data = data)
```

- Removed 'jsonify' and disabled escaping for {{data}}

  de = {% autoescape false %} {{data}} {% endautoescape %}

Comment: A better way is to use Jinja2 filters: `var de = {{ data|tojson|safe }};`